# What instead of Sram Spectro s7 shifter

Tags: commuter, sram

I have just damaged shifter and it is no longer usable. Is it possible to replace it with something cheaper and more available? It is just commuter/winter-bike, so I just need it to work and less it costs, better it is.

[image: from comment]

Comment: I suppose you're from Poland. You can get brand new for 92 PLN. If you want sth cheaper the only option is to buy friction shifter as suggested below or fixing the shifter on your own. LBS is not an option, hub is rare here, it is highly unlikely they will have (cheap) spare 2nd-hand parts. Could you post a photo of broken one and show what the problem is?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/bpnIE

as you can see, this broken thing pushes spring inside shifter.

Comment: The cheapest option is drilling in grip and putting there some metal replacement for broken part. For half of the price you can get S5 shifter - broken part *_may_* be iterchangeable. Last, but probably the best option is to search for used parts. You didn't confirmed, but I still assume you're in Poland. Have look at this bunch of offers: https://www.olx.pl/oferta/sram-s7-piasta-z-kolem-26-grip-linka-kpl-zestaw-CID767-IDq9I9L.html#acbf1f5c6c https://www.olx.pl/oferta/sram-s7-1900mm-CID767-IDqohJf.html#acbf1f5c6c

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Go to your local bike shop and ask for something used out of their parts bin. They’ll often have shifters left over when someone upgraded.</strike>

<strike>My bike shop would throw in the part for free if I paid for labor, but in either case the cost would be trivial. It’d be worth it to get the derailleur cable (both inners and others) replaced at the same time.</strike>

Reading Sheldon’s page on [Sachs/SRAM IGH](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/sachs-internal.html) it appears that the cable pull for that particular seven speed internal gear hub may not be standard. It may be better to just replace like with like. Again, your local bike shop may have the spare part in their parts bin. A local maker space may be also able to fabricate the part out of nylon or abs using their 3d printer.

If you just need it to work, a friction shifter will work with just about anything. Your bike shop should be able to give you one for free or close to free.

Comment: In general, IGH shifters are relatively specific compared to derailleur shifters. Friction shifting isn't a great idea on higher speed IGH hubs (more than 3 speeds); at best, it ends up being pretty sloppy. I don't know about this specific model, but Sheldon recommends http://rideyourbike.com/ for IGH parts.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn’t have suggested friction if the OP hadn’t said he just needed it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The cheapest option is drilling in grip and putting there some metal replacement for broken part. For half of the price you can get S5 shifter - broken part *may* be iterchangeable. Last, but probably the best option is to search for used parts. You didn't confirmed, but I still assume you're in Poland. Have look at this bunch of offers:

1. [Good value for shifter and whole hub for spare parts source](https://www.olx.pl/oferta/sram-s7-piasta-z-kolem-26-grip-linka-kpl-zestaw-CID767-IDq9I9L.html#acbf1f5c6c)
2. [Reasonable](https://www.olx.pl/oferta/sram-s7-1900mm-CID767-IDqohJf.html#acbf1f5c6c)

Comment: Yep, I'm form Poland ;) Just forgotten to mention it :)

I do not really need all of the 7 gears, 5 would be enough so I will consider buying S5 shifter too. Thank you for helping me :)

P.S. I hate these commuter/urban  systems, bleh :O

Comment: @moorzyn Manetka od S5 nie będzie pasowała. Prawie na pewno interwały się nie zgadzają. Chodziło mi o to, że możesz jedynie próbować wymienić samą obrotową część. Ta z olx za 60 jest tylko trochę droższa, a będzie pasować idealnie (z dokładnością do tego, że jest na lewą stronę), więc poszedłbym w tym kierunku.